# Word Addin - Set an custom IBeam cursor for the document

Tags: .net, ms-word, cursor, word-addins

How I can set an custom IBeam cursor for Word document?

I create the cursor from bitmat with belowe code:

```
Dim myCur = New Cursor(bmp.GetHicon)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model does not provide a way to modify the cursor used by the various cursor types (Word.WdCursorType enumeration). It takes the default type of the system its running on. That's why the Cursor object is a property of the SYSTEM object: WordApp.System.Cursor

So you'd need to change the cursor for Windows and I assume this is done using the Windows API, however that may be done using VB.NET...